# How do I edit the keymap of Cinnamon without using Cinnamon Settings?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I would like to edit my keyboard shortcuts in Cinnamon but using the graphical user interface for editing them (i.e., Cinnamon Settings) is not an option as it keeps crashing on me ([here](https://bugs.sabayon.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5124) is my bug report on this, if you're wondering), is there a way I can edit the keyboard shortcuts without using the graphical user interface (GUI)? For example, under LXDE (or any DE using Openbox as its window manager) I would edit `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` in a text editor to edit the keyboard shortcuts without using a GUI, is there a similar way to edit the keyboard shortcuts of Cinnamon?